# Recursive function with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some web automation using selenium in python, and if my script encounters any errors I want the whole process to restart again (an infinite loop)
so basically I tried to use a recursive function and recall it each time an error occurred, it looks like this :

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

def my_func():
    try :
        driver.get("https://mywebsite.com")
        .
        .
        .
    except Exception as E : 
        print(str(E)) #printing the exception message
        driver.quit() #quitting from the current tab
        my_func() #recalling the function again 

my_func()
```

the first time everything works fine and when an error occurs (because the website switch to another page) it prints this Exception: `Message: element not interactable`  which is totally normal, but on the second iteration I get this :

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=59887): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/6d23ab3406dbef8f6581c4c7652d2633/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000019D2BA3CC10>: Failed to establish a new connection: `[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

so is there any way to fix this error or other better solutions for this script?

Comment: This just means your sending requests too fast add a time.sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the message:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

It may be a security issue that resulted from the target URL. Try to connect to the internet via another connection such as a mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I have to create a new driver on each iteration, also I added a time.sleep before recalling the function just in case the requests were sent too fast  :

```
def my_func():
    try :
        PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
        driver.get("https://mywebsite.com")
        .
        .
        .
    except Exception as E : 
        print(str(E)) #printing the exception message
        driver.quit() #quitting from the current tab
        time.sleep(5)
        my_func() #recalling the function again 

my_func()
```